# Use variable as 'src' in 'video' tag - using document's URL to create filename variable

Tags: html, video

I am trying to use a variable (based on a parameter passed with the document URL) to play a video using the HTML5 video tag.

I have an HTML5 page that lists a bunch of procedures. I have created .mp4 videos for each of the procedures that are located in a directory below the level of the originating HTML page. This is all intended to run on a CD or a hard drive; no internet or any type of server is being used.

Currently I use the `<a>` tag's href parameter to directly open the video.  This works, but I wondered if it would be better to open a 2nd HTML5 page that has the video embedded, since that is now native to HTML5.

I thought I would use a single HTML page to play the videos with the name of the video being sent from the first HTML page based on the user's selection:  HTML page 1 - user clicks procedure - open 2nd html page with parameter at end of URL.  In the second HTML page, parse URL to get video name, use this variable as the 'src' in the video tag:

```
<video controls >
    <source src=v+".mp4" >
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

but that doesn't work. It doesn't seem to understand the variable.  I've tried building the variable in several ways.

Instead my solution is to create an HTML page for each specific .mp4 file, and to hard code the video filename in each separate HTML page. There has to be an easier way. Do you have any suggestions?

I have only a basic knowledge of HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use Javascript to (a) find the variable from the URL and (b) write that into the document when it is displayed.

the example below includes some code to grab the parameter, and then uses that function to get the parameter called `v` and, if it exists, use that to write the `<video>` tag:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
// split the querystring parameters on the URL and find the requested one
function getParam(parameterName) {
    var result = null, tmp = [];
    var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        tmp = items[index].split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    }
    return result;
}

v = getParam("v")
if (v===null) {
    document.write("<p>You need to add a ?v={filename} to the url")
} else {
    document.write("<video controls>")
    document.write("<source src=\""+v+".mp4\" >")
    document.write("Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.")
    document.write("</video>")
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked!  I didn't realize I needed that 2nd part about writing the video tag out in code!  thank you thank you